# LUA scene transitions

Tags: lua, coronasdk

how can I make a new scene in Lua, especially corona? the only thing that I can think of are, removing all displayed things in my app, or loading another .lua file, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new scene you use [`storyboard.newScene()` function](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/newScene.html). Lua itself has nothing to do with scenes, it's Corona SDK "abstraction" of a view (screen).

I recommend you to start by reading [Storyboard API reference](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html). The documentation in Corona is pretty solid with large number of samples.